# How to convert String into a HTML element in Next JS Application?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I have saved the product description as the HTML elements into a Database like this. But when I am rendering this data into div, this is displaying as String. I want to display all the data like HTML elements in my **Next JS application**. I tried JSON.parse, but it's not working.

If someone can help me to fix this will be appreciated.

```
{
"images": [
{
"alternativeText": "cinnamon",
"path": "public/uploads/5585.jpg"
}
],
"_id": "606c39c884372a0e20c3f9bb",
"name": "Cinnamon",
"code": "5586",
"price": 49,
"category": {
"_id": "6064b37855bd0f26e0df4616",
"name": "Natural Essential Oils",
"createdAt": "2021-03-31T17:38:00.066Z",
"updatedAt": "2021-03-31T17:38:24.398Z",
"__v": 0
},
"description": "<p>Cinnamon Bark Vitality&trade; essential oil has a warm, spicy flavor that complements a variety of classic culinary treats and drinks. Cinnamon Bark Vitality is not only great for elevating dishes, but it can also be taken as a dietary supplement and is an important ingredient in some of Young Living&rsquo;s most popular products, including Thieves&reg; Vitality&trade; and Inner Defense&trade;. Cinnamon Bark Vitality&rsquo;s warm taste and nostalgic notes bring a spicy addition to your favorite dishes. By using Cinnamon Bark Vitality as a dietary supplement, you can help support healthy digestive and immune systems.</p>",
"createdAt": "2021-04-06T10:36:56.440Z",
"updatedAt": "2021-04-06T10:36:56.440Z",
"__v": 0
}
```

Check the image attachment.
[image]

Next Js application code

```
const Product = ({product}) => {
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <Head>
                <title>Product</title>
            </Head>
            <Layout>
                <div className="container-fluid product-page">
                    <div className="page-body">
                        <div className="row product">
                            <div className="col-xl-5 col-lg-5 image-box">
                                <div className="preview-image">
                                    <div className="image">
                                        <img
                                            src={ImageRootPath + "/" + product.images[0].path}
                                            alt={product.images[0].alternativeText}
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-xl-7 col-lg-7 info-box">
                                <div className="product-info">
                                    <div className="product-name">
                                        <h4>{product.name}</h4>
                                        <p>{"Product code: " + product.code}</p>
                                        <hr/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="product-price">
                                        <h5>Price: <span>{product.price + "$"}</span></h5>
                                        <p>{"Quantity: 5ml"}</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="product-des">
                                        {product.description}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Layout>
        </Fragment>
    );
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by **displaying as HTML element**? HTML tags must be displayed, is that what you mean?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As you want to display raw HTML, so this

```
<div className="product-des">
  {product.description}
</div>
```

should be changed to

```
<div className="product-des" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: product.description }}>
```

This is covered in the [official doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

> `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is React’s replacement for using `innerHTML` in the browser DOM [...] you have to type out `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` and pass *an object with a `__html` key*

And you also have to be mindful of the risky to set raw HTML in the case like this

> In general, setting HTML from code is risky because it’s easy to inadvertently expose your users to a cross-site scripting (XSS) attack